# Unknown error with phonegap file reader

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, filereader

Using phonegap 2.9.0, using this callback to read file:

```
    fBrowse.params.on_file_select = function(file){     // file: FileEntry  
        try{
            var reader = new FileReader();
            jsIQ.msg('loading game!..');
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                // success
                var game = null;
                // remove garbage from string
            jsIQ.msg('loading game!3..' + arguments.length);
            jsIQ.msg('loading game!3/2: ' + evt.target.result);
            //jsIQ.msg('data: ' + evt.target.result, 2);
                var s = $.trim(B64.decode(evt.target.result));
            jsIQ.msg('loading game!4..');
                s = s.substr(0, s.indexOf('}')+ 1);
            jsIQ.msg('loading game!5..');
                game = JSON.parse( s );
                if (game != null) {
                    // success!
                    $('#fBrowse').hide();
                    jsIQ.msg('Load game success', 2);
                    jsIQ.triggerEvent('heart_game_loaded', {data: game});
                }
            };
            reader.onerror = function(){
                alert('error reading file');
            };
            jsIQ.msg('loading game!2..');
            file.file(function(f){
                reader.readAsText(f);
            }, function(){
                alert('Error opening file');
            });
        } catch (e){
            jsIQ.msg('loadgame err: ' + e.message, 2);
            alert('Внутренняя ошибка');
        }
        //return true;
    };
```

and i see this log file contents:

...

[-] 17:1:26.257 Load game file: /mnt/sdcard/heartofice/heartofice2.savegame

[-] 17:1:26.260 loading game!..

[-] 17:1:26.262 loading game!2..

[-] 17:1:26.270 loading game!3..1

this means, the line with

```
evt.target.result
```

is falling with error WITHOUT any notices! "evt" have been passed to success read callback, but i can't use it??

This happens on real android device (4.0.3)

Tried to use "reader.result" from onload callback, but got same behavior!

How to solve this?

Comment: And i tried to use onloadend event - same result...

Comment: Do you get any errors in logcat? logcat would surface any of the JavaScript console errors as well. You could try doing something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(evt))` to see if the `evt` object looks like what you expect.

Comment: jsIQ.msg do the same log as console.log, but in external file. But any kind of use "evt" breaks this function: typeof(evt), if (!evt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

jsIQ.msg uses a FileWriter to put data to log

So, when I "got a file", I messaged it to log - this breaks a link to "readed file", and it becomes obsolete.

As so, never use combination:

1. get file#1 for read
2. get file#2 for write, write
3. read file#1

Reasons of this behavior are unknown...